# how to reverse divide 1/f on fpu?

Tags: assembly, x86, fpu

Sorry for such simple question, (learning assembly from few 
days) but i was browsing through books and couldnt find answer

what is a proper quick way to count 1/f where f is some 
float on x86 fpu

is it

```
    fld dword [ebp+8]
    fld1
    fdivrp            ; fdivrp st0 st1 ?
```

?

it is proper (im mean literally cause i am not sure as to fdivr args)
or is some quickest simplest way ?

//EDIT

Is this a best way to div 1/f (or 1/sqrt(f) in classical fpu asm ?
(without sse, and without carmack trick -  I will try it l8er, now I'm
tryin just do 'proper fpu'  )

Comment: Without dirty tricks or SSE, there is nothing special you can do.

Answer (score 4):

From the Intel CPU doc:

> FDIVRP - Divide ST(0) by ST(1), store result in ST(1), and pop the register stack.

Read the doc.

Comment: allright, checked it and it seem to be working (sloow 43 cycles :( ) But I am reasonably new in fpu asm (renewing contact to be precise after 15 years) and I am not sure if it is the fastest way, (I am not talkimg about SSE simply fpu) Is there maybe some distinct instructions to quick calculate 1/float (or 1/sqrt(float) - I am trying to write 'normalize vector of floats' in fpu asembly :(

Comment: @grungefightr there are some crazy tricks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) but why not just use SSE?

Comment: @harold - i will use SSE/AVX, sure, i like it :) But now I am trying to understand fpu - above trick is also nice, like such things too ;-) Got some 'simply fpu' tutorial for example, but canntot fins some nice sources of fpu routines to learn from it (google in not so much terribly helpful in fpu/sse - often cannot find things i searching for, in fpu theme)

Comment: you can do non-floating calculations while fpu is busy with divison

Comment: dont forget to make equally located fpu-divison instructions. Example: 1 division then 20-30 ALU instructions than 1 division again and than 20-30 ALU again